# open up connections on different source ports in Jmeter

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, jmeter, cloud, load-testing

I am trying to execute the load tets with single VM, it can handle 100 concurrent connections. I checked with DevOps team they suggest me to configure my Jmeter to open up many connections on different source ports. How that can be done in Jmeter?

I am testing on cloud machine

Answer (score 1):

If your DevOPs suggest to configure JMeter to open connections on different source [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)) you should suggest them to quit IT and become rickshaws.

When JMeter (or any other tool) establishes a TCP connection it uses a new port on client side **by default**.

It is not possible to open several connections using same network port

Demo:

[image]

If you misunderstood them and you need to send requests using different source [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) - this is something you could do as well, at "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler there is "Source address" input where you can specify the IP address you want to use:

[image]

Just make sure that the IP address or its alias exists at the operating system level. More information: [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter)